# running scheme from emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, scheme

I'm a newbie to LISP.

I am attempting to invoke the scheme interpreter from within emacs (version 23 running on windows). I loaded the xscheme library by telling emacs to `M-x load-library` and then entering `xscheme` at the prompt in the minibuffer. The library loaded, and then I issued the `M-x run-scheme` command. (I realize that all this loading can be done from .emacs at startup, but I am not concerned with that at the moment.)

So far so good - the `*scheme*` buffer has been created, and now I'm hoping that I'm able to talk to the scheme interpreter.

However, when I try to evaluate something in that `*scheme*`buffer (e.g. `(define shoe-size 14)`), I get this `Output file descriptor of scheme is closed` message in the minibuffer.

Does anybody know how to fix this in emacs?

(Also, how does one set the major-mode as REPL in the `*scheme*` buffer?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try setting the `scheme-program-name` variable to the path to your Scheme interpreter. The major-mode of the scheme buffer is probably just `comint` and you cannot do much about it unless you switch to something more capable like [Geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) - something that I'd recommend you do.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on Geizer - I just installed it and the REPL mode seems to be working for me. I'll experiment with it a bit and will be checking back for answers later.

Comment: Hello, I installed the Geizer package and was able to interact with guile ('M-x run-guile'). However, if I load a file with .scm extension (which opens it in a buffer in Scheme Guile major mode), and try to compile it ('C-c C-k'), I get the message _No Geiser REPL for this buffer_. (I may be in a bit of a catch22 as a newbie: the need to set up emacs environment to be able to learn scheme, clisp, and emacslisp on one hand, and a need to know at least some emacslisp to be able to set up that environment on the other.) Thanks in advance to anyone who's able to comment on this. d.

Comment: @dave, I have encountered this problem, fix by using guile 2.0.x, geiser doesn't support guile 1.x.

Answer (score 9):

Add this line to your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq scheme-program-name "gsi")
```

(Replace `"gsi"` with the name of your Scheme interpreter.)

You can then start the interpreter with `M-x run-scheme`.  You can evaluate pieces of code by using `C-x C-e` (to evaluate the sexp before the point) or with `C-M-x` to evaluate the sexp you're in right now.  You can also load a file with `C-c C-l`.

Answer (score 5):

I'll start by saying that I'm very new to programming, scheme and SICP, but I'm trying to work through the course and watch the lectures that are online.
I'm running **emacs on Ubuntu 12.10** and I really wanted to get MIT scheme working in emacs instead of relying on Edwin.
The above tips didn't work for me, but here's the step-by-step instructions that did work:

1. Install emacs 24 from the Ubuntu Software Center (search "emacs" and install it!)
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>)
3. Go to your home directory (`cd ~`)
4. Open the hidden file `.emacs` in gedit (`gedit .emacs`)
5. On the first line of the file, type exactly what's after the colon: **(require 'xscheme)**
6. Save the changes to `.emacs`
7. That's it!!!

You can now open `.scm` files in emacs and use commands like `C-x` `C-e`.

*directions courtesy of http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsScheme.html#sec14

Answer (score 0):

[My guess is that it's just a known issue](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/geiser-users/2013-04/msg00013.html) I still dunno how to sort that out (it's out of my current skills) but I got a macro that probably helps: just after writing the s-exp you can do `Cc-Cz` (it calls the geiser REPL) then `C-spc, C-M-b, M-w, C-x-o, C-y` and `RET`.

There are a variation (same, placed just after writing the s-exp): `C-spc, C-M-b, M-w, C-c Cz, C-y` and `RET`