# Is there way to run MIT scheme interpreter under emacs on Windows?

Tags: emacs, scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

I am a newbie for Lisp, and trying to run MIT scheme interpreter under emacs on Windows. But info seems all indicate that this is impossible.
http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall05/ai/scheme/starting.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/

So I wonder if there is a way to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.  You'd obviously need to add your paths. If I omit the `--library` option, then upon startup mit-scheme complains about not finding it's runtime band.

```
(require 'cmuscheme)
(setq scheme-program-name "/usr/local/scheme/bin/mit-scheme --library /usr/local/scheme/lib/mit-scheme")
```

In the *scheme* buffer:

```
MIT/GNU Scheme running under MacOSX
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2011 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Tuesday November 8, 2011 at 10:45:46 PM
  Release 9.1.1     || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41
  LIAR/x86-64 4.118 || Edwin 3.116

1 ]=>
```

Answer (score 0):

I run on Linux emacs with xscheme:
https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/GNU-Emacs-Interface.html

It was rather easy to install. See this question about it's installation. He seemed to get it running OK:
[running scheme from emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603512/running-scheme-from-emacs)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried what you want on WINDOWS 7, independent terminal could be popped up outside emacs but with error info in REPL. 
It seems that there was no official support for this feature on windows, Racket works fine with the geiser package, maybe you could try it.

https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/GNU-Emacs-Interface.html#GNU-Emacs-Interface

> This interface works under unix only, because it requires unix signals for its operation.
>   Porting it to Windows would require reimplementing the interface to eliminate the use of
>   signals. We have no plans to do this.
>   To invoke Scheme from Emacs, load the xscheme library, then use M-x run-scheme. You
>   may give run-scheme a prefx argument, in which case it will allow you to edit the command
>   line that is used to invoke Scheme. Do not remove the --emacs option!

Answer (score 0):

There are [instructions for getting Chez Scheme working with Emacs on Windows](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/b351-leak/emacs-scheme.html). It might be possible to translate those instructions to MIT Scheme.

However, an alternative option is to use [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) with the [SICP language mode](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html). Once the package is installed, using Scheme is simple:

> To use the sicp language simply use #lang sicp as the first line of your program.

This is what I'm currently using to edit SICP code on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Emacs in Windows, together with Scheme in WSL2, and set `scheme-program-name` to `wsl scheme`:

```lisp
(setq scheme-program-name "wsl scheme")
```

Then run `run scheme` will Enter into the Scheme.